# Setting the MailComposer's toolbar style

Tags: iphone

How is the MFMailComposeViewController's top bar's style set?

Is this a navigation bar?

I read the docs and cant seem to find how to set this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible unfortunately:

> Important: The mail composition
>   interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your
>   application. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your
>   application is not allowed to make
>   further changes to the email content.
>   The user may still edit the content
>   using the interface, but programmatic
>   changes are ignored. Thus, you must
>   set the values of content fields
>   before presenting the interface.

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html